# Applying Edge Correction in ArcGIS Average Nearest Neighbor?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-statistics, nearest-neighbor

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 with the tool [Average Nearest Neighbor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/average-nearest-neighbor.htm) from the Spatial Statistics toolbox to describe the data. I want to avoid mistakes caused by Edge Effect.

In the Ripleys K Function tool there is an option to control that (there are a few options of what to do with Edge Effect correction) but not in Average Nearest Neighbor.

How can I avoid Edge Effect mistakes while using Average Nearest Neighbor tool?

Comment: Sorry, you would have to modify the underlying Python code to include an edge correction for NNI.

Comment: but the calculation seems to be from an arcgis DLL (gapy package)

Comment: In my version of Desktop ArcGIS 10.2 the tool is pointing to: "C:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts\NearestNeighbor.py".

Comment: the tool is, but this is merely a wrapper. It's a phoney open source like many ESRI tools

Comment: Create input larger than you need and then crop your output?